# search words with query in a knowledge base with python

Tags: python, rdf, data-mining, wikipedia, knowledge-graph

I should write a program that given some words (for example token ocrs) to a knowledge base (like wikipedia or dbpedia or wikidata) and search that words in that knowledge base  by the query that we wrote (for example with rdf) then it will find those related words and give their weight too.
I searched a lot and all of them enter a page, for example, wikidata, and extract all the related details about a specific address, but I want every word to be anywhere in wikidata.(in other words search the relevant words from the KB and use the relevant words as extended OCR tokens). I would be grateful if anyone has done this before or could be help. (I attach that source that I search in internet that it is for one page but I want for any word in all of knowledge)

````
from rdflib import Graph,URIRef
from rdflib.namespace import RDFS, SKOS
g=Graph()
g.parse('https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q2831.ttl')
MJ=URIRef('http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2831')
for label in g.objects(MJ, SKOS.altLabel):
    print(label.value, label.language)
```
````

Comment: you have to use a SPARQL service or e.g. use the Wikidata API to search for entities on Wikidata based on some tokens.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for reply . could you give me an example to get one word and search in wikidata with sparql?

Comment: @UninformedUser Hi, thank you so much for reply . could you give me an example to get one word and search in wikidata with sparql?